# Reading and using a CSV file in jQuery

Tags: jquery, csv, include, jquery-csv

I have the following issue:

I have a large CSV file with a lot of data that i need to use on an (external (ofcourse approved!)) webpage, utilizing only jQuery.

I found [jQuery-csv](http://evanplaice.github.io/jquery-csv/examples/basic-usage.html) to be able to manipulate the csv-data into an array. Once i have the data in an array, i'm confident i will be able to do everything i need to do. However, i don't quite get where and how i should 'include' my csv file. It is hosted, available through an url. jQuery-csv never seems to link to a file however, and their demo pages only show content being used through an in-page `<input>` tag.

To give some extra depth to the situation: A customer wants to use his .csv file-database with a lot of sentences ('i enjoyed this!') and display these sentences at random on his site.

tl;dr: How do i load a .csv file onto my page, so i can use it with jQuery-csv?

Comment: Do you want the user to load the file client-side or do you want to load the data via an AJAX request?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*How do i load a .csv file onto my page*

You can use `.ajax()`, Something like

```
$.ajax({
    url: "Path/YourFileName.csv",
    async: false,
    success: function (csvd) {
        data = $.csv.toArrays(csvd);
    },
    dataType: "text",
    complete: function () {
        // call a function on complete 
    }
});
```

**Do load [jQuery-csv](https://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv) plugin.** before using `$.csv.toArrays`